# The values of several non-ascii keys in x86

Tags: assembly, x86

what are the values of the keyboard keys:
Esc , up arrow, down arrow, left arrow, right arrow, tab, shift, enter and space?
I want to use them in a game I am writing in x86 and I want to detect if those key were pressed by the player with the `ax, 0 int 16h` interrupt. Thank you all for helping me

Comment: Sounds like you want to read raw scan-codes, not terminal input, if you want to detect presses of shift keys and so on.  Google `bios scan codes` if you want to do it using BIOS input functions like AH=0 / int 16h (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_16H)

Comment: ESC has an ASCII code: 27 (decimal)

Comment: [What are the scan codes for keyboard arrows? (right,left,down,up)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23188540) is a partial duplicate, but unfortunately doesn't link where to find more for keys it doesn't mention.  With an edit to add a reference for such info, it could maybe work as a duplicate.  Of course, you can just try it (e.g. in a debugger).

Comment: Note that the scan codes for keys are not a property of the x86 architecture but rather of the computer built around it.  In your case, you are working on a PC, so it's a detail of the PC architecture.